# Testing Angular Directive To External API: $apply and $digest

Tags: angularjs

I have an Angular directive that connects to an external JavaScript API. Because the API call is not wrapped by Angular I need to call `$scope.$apply` to apply the updates from the API call.

I do this in the `link` function of the directive:

```
function link(scope, element, attrs) {
  externalService.doSomethingInteresting(
    function(result) {
      scope.$apply(function() {
        scope.applyResult(result);
      });
    }
  );
}
```

I have this service faked for my test, just calling the callback with some canned data:

```
function doSomethingInteresting(callback) {
  callback(goodResult);
}
```

When I test this directive (Karma+Jasmine), I call `scope.$digest` as in the [Angular testing guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).

```
var rawElement = angular.element("<myDirective></myDirective>");
var element = compile(rawElement)(scope);

scope.$digest();
```

However, this leads to:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

I understand this is because of the `$scope.apply` combined with the `scope.$digest()` call. If I don't call `scope.$digest()` then my `element` is empty. So I don't know how to get the result of the API call applied, but also ready the result of the compile.

Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: I think you should wrap your externalService in angular service and inject it into your directive. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/3wjojn5u/).

Comment: It took me a while to digest your Fiddle @themyth92. So you're using $timeout to make the faked service async. Very nice! That makes sense to me. So each time I make a call that involves the faked service, I just flush the timeout. If you convert this to an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Added as answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mock your service using async `$timeout` instead of purely synchronous code so that you will not get the `Error: $digest already in progress`.

```
module('myApp', function($provide){
  $provide.provider('myService', function() {
    this.$get = function($timeout) {
      return {

        // mock your service
        doSomethingInteresting : function(callback) {
          return $timeout(function() {
            callback(mockData);
          });
        }
      }
    }
  });
});
```

And then after your `scope.$digest()` in creating directive, you **flush** `$timeout` to make the callback execute.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/themyth92/3wjojn5u/)